# How to return the value instead of key by completing-read

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, completion

```
(completing-read
 "Complete a foo: "
 '(("foobar1" "~/foobar1/") ("barfoo" "/usr/barfoo/") ("foobaz" "/hello/")))
```

As shown above, I would like to prompt for `"foobar1"`,`"barfoo"`, and `"foobaz"` but getting the paired directory in return.

Moverover, if I have a hash-table like this

```
(cl-defstruct person ID name)
(setq person-object (make-person :ID 123 :name "foo"))
(setq person-table (make-hash-table))
(pushash (person-ID person-object) person-object person-table)
```

How can I prompt for the person name but getting a person ID in return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@legoscia provided a good answer: `completing-read` does *not* give you access to the value associated with a key that it uses for completion.  E.g., for an alist `COLLECTION` argument, it does not give you access to the cdr of a chosen alist key.

For an alist you can use `assoc` to get the *first* matching alist element, and for a hash table you can `maphash` or do a get.

But these approaches *preclude getting the particular value* associated with a particular chosen key occurrence *when there are* ***duplicates*** *of the key*, that is, when *multiple candidates have the same key*, or name.

You cannot get the 2nd matching element, or the 13th. In fact, vanilla Emacs `completing-read` *eliminates duplication* of completion candidates that have the same key (name). For vanilla Emacs, any information in *the cdr of an alist entry is wasted*. You can use an alist, for convenience, if you already have one, but if not then you might as well just use a list of names (strings or symbols), not conses.

If you use [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then alist entries are not wasted. There is no problem retrieving cdr values. You can easily get to the complete information of a candidate you choose, after `completing-read` is done.

**Icicles** does this by using propertized strings as candidates, and by enhancing `completing-read` so that it can return the complete string, properties and all, that a user chooses. You can recuperate the complete alist entry from the propertized string that is returned.

***When is it important*** *to be able to have and use duplicate keys that can have different associated values? And how can a user tell them apart (e.g., in `*Completions*`), if they are duplicates?*

Examples:

- Bookmarks that have the same name but are for different targets - for example, for different files with the same relative name in different directories.
- Lines or other text in a buffer that match a pattern or that contain a marker. This includes matches in [**Icicles** search](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview), where you can define search contexts any way you like (not just lines). It also includes buffer zones (including restrictions, aka narrowings) and buffer positions (markers).
- Candidates that have the same text but whose annotations are different. (User input is not matched against annotations shown in `*Completions*`.)
- Imenu items that have the same name, e.g., multiple definitions of objects (e.g. functions) that have the same name.
- Tagged items (e.g. functions) that have the same name.
- Candidates that are other Lisp objects, such as frames, that can have the same name.

In **Icicles**, how does a user choose one among several completion candidates that have the same name?

- Users can control the *order* (sorting) of the candidates, including changing order on the fly. `*Completions*` shows them to you in a specific order. You can cycle among candidates or choose any of them directly. You are not limited to matching, to choose. (With duplicate candidates, matching can be insufficient to get you to only one of them.)
- `*Completions*` can also show you additional information about candidates, which distinguishes them even when they have the same name/text.  Such info could be surrounding text (if the candidates are matching buffer text), or candidate metadata (e.g. file or bookmark attributes).
- You can also see important additional information about the current candidate (e.g. during cycling) in the mode line.
- You can get additional information (complete `*Help*`) about the current candidate on demand, by hitting a key.

*What do you have to do, to be able to take advantage of this **Icicles** feature* ***in your own code?***

See [Defining Tripping Commands](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Defining_Tripping_Commands) for how to define your own commands that let users trip among (explore) candidates might have associated positional or other navigational information. (See [Tripping](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Tripping) for predefined **Icicles** tripping commands.)

A brief overview of what to do in your command:

1. Bind variable `icicle-whole-candidate-as-text-prop-p` to non-`nil`.
2. Set variable `icicle-candidates-alist` to the alist that you pass to `completing-read`. This has the effect of encoding, as a text property on the candidate display string, the entire corresponding original alist entry.
3. Use `icicle-get-alist-candidate` after calling `completing-read`, to recover that complete information about the candidate the user chooses, that is, the complete alist element, kncluding the cdr.

(See also: [Note to programmers using Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Note_to_Programmers).)

Comment: @legoscia gives all infomation I need. However, I choose this answer because it alerts me the duplication issue.

Answer (score 8):

There's no way to get `completing-read` to return the value instead of the key, so you have to do the lookup yourself:

```
(let ((completions '(("foobar1" "~/foobar1/") ("barfoo" "/usr/barfoo/") ("foobaz" "/hello/"))))
  (cadr (assoc (completing-read "Complete a foo: " completions) completions)))
```

As for the hash table, since the name is not the key, you need to iterate through every object in the hash table to find it, using `maphash`.  Since it would be wasteful to keep iterating after you've found what you're looking for, you could use `catch` and `throw`, like this:

```
(catch 'found-it
  (maphash
   (lambda (key value)
     (when (equal (person-name value) desired-name)
       (throw 'found-it key)))
   person-table))
```

This will return the person ID, or `nil` if there's no person whose name equals `desired-name`.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.howardism.org/Technical/Emacs/alt-completing-read.html

You have been looking for alt-completing-read !
Simpler version

```
(let ((choices '(("First"  . 'first-choice)
                 ("Second" . 'second-choice)
                 ("Third"  . 'third-choice))))
  (alist-get
   (completing-read "Choose: " choices)
   choices nil nil 'equal))
```

Complex version

```
(defun alt-completing-read (prompt collection &optional predicate require-match initial-input hist def inherit-input-method)
  "Calls `completing-read' but returns the value from COLLECTION.

Simple wrapper around the `completing-read' function that assumes
the collection is either an alist, or a hash-table, and returns
the _value_ of the choice, not the selected choice. For instance,
give a variable of choices like:

    (defvar favorite-hosts '((\"Glamdring\" . \"192.168.5.12\")
                             (\"Orcrist\"   . \"192.168.5.10\")
                             (\"Sting\"     . \"192.168.5.220\")
                             (\"Gungnir\"   . \"192.168.5.25\")))

We can use this function to `interactive' without needing to call
`alist-get' afterwards:

    (defun favorite-ssh (hostname)
      \"Start a SSH session to a given HOSTNAME.\"
      (interactive (list (alt-completing-read \"Host: \" favorite-hosts)))
      (message \"Rockin' and rollin' to %s\" hostname))"

  ;; Yes, Emacs really should have an `alistp' predicate to make this code more readable:
  (cl-flet ((assoc-list-p (obj) (and (listp obj) (consp (car obj)))))

    (let* ((choice
            (completing-read prompt collection predicate require-match initial-input hist def inherit-input-method))
           (results (cond
                     ((hash-table-p collection) (gethash choice collection))
                     ((assoc-list-p collection) (alist-get choice collection def nil 'equal))
                     (t                         choice))))
      (if (listp results) (first results) results))))
```